# Automate clicking of menu item and opening file - Windows XP

Tags: python, windows, import, automation, windows-xp

I have a windows XP computer, that is running LaserCut 5.3.

I would like to automate the process of importing a DXF file, which I do by going File > Import > [selecting DXF] > Clicking Import.

The DXF file is always in the same location. (C:\autoCut\receivedFile.dxf)

Is there any way I can automate the clicking through of importing the file?

The computer runs Windows XP Professional and has Python 2.7 installed. As it is a school computer, I would rather not install extra programs, but can do if it is the only way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at pywinauto:

http://pywinauto.github.io/

There's also the swapy project, which might be useful for getting a head start on generating your pywinauto code:

https://code.google.com/p/swapy/

Answer (score 0):

Use [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) - Automation tool.

You can also use these sikuli libraries into your java program to automate your application.

How to use Sikuli with Java program - [reference](http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/030-java-dev.html)